Why does this exception class produce a garbage message?
class MyException: public std::exception
{
  private:
   std::string m_message;
   bool m_internalError;
  
  public:
   MyException(bool internal_err, std::string msg)
   : m_message(std::move(msg)), 
     m_internalError(internal_err)
   {
   }

   const char* what() const noexcept override
   {
      std::ostringstream msg;
      msg << m_internalError << ": " << m_message;
      std::string full_msg = msg.str();
      return full_msg.c_str();
   }
}

This works fine on windows, but on linux, contains exception contains a garbage message. What could be the reason?
If I remove m_message from the ostringstream, it works fine, but not sure why it causes issue as is only on linux.

When do you think the buffer pointed by full_msg.c_str() is destroyed?

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. The behaviour is undefined. Use the address sanitizer for more insight.

You could initialize m_message with the formatted m_internalError << ":" << m_message in the constructor rather than upon calling what.  Then returning m_message.c_str() in what should work because m_message is a member variable.  But retutning full_msg.c_str() is undefined behaviour  (returning a pointer to a local variable that is destroyed when the function exits).

The c_str member function on a std::string returns a pointer to a buffer, but that buffer is invalidated when the owning std::string is destroyed.
You need for the C-string to outlive the lifetime of the what function. You could dynamically allocate with new but then you potentially have a memory leak if you don't explicitly delete the error message on catching the exception. This is ugly.
As per comments, the better solution is to initialize a std::string with the exception. As the string is now a member variable, the pointer will not be invalidated, and the string will be automatically freed when the exception instance is destroyed.
class MyException: public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string m_message;
    bool m_internalError;
    std::string what_msg;

public:
    MyException(bool internal_err, std::string msg)
    : m_message(std::move(msg)), 
      m_internalError(internal_err)
    {
        // Initialize what_msg
    }

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return what_msg.c_str();
    }
};

